# Is there any way to reverse the order of "Sales price" and "Regular prcie" in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce, product

Usually it will be displayed as "Regular price" first with a cross line and "Sale price" second . I wish to reverse the order . Researched on google about it,nothing worked . anyone implemented ??

Comment: It's almost universal that the *last* displayed price is the one that the customer is going to pay. Have you got a strong reason for going against that convention?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one of the solution which you can use

```
add_filter('woocommerce_sale_price_html', 'wdm_change_price_text', 10, 2);

function wdm_change_price_text( $price, $this_object ) {
    $display_price       = $this_object->get_display_price();
    $display_regular_price   = $this_object->get_display_price($this_object->get_regular_price());
    $price='<ins>' . wc_price($display_price) . '</ins>' . $this_object->get_price_suffix() . '<del>' . wc_price($display_regular_price) . '</del> ';
    return $price;
}
```

Addition there are other filter for different types of product so you might also need to add the function to them too.

```
//woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html
//woocommerce_variation_sale_price_html
//woocommerce_free_sale_price_html
```

**Previous Price**

[image]

**After Customization Using the above code**

[image]

Have tested the code it works for me. Try the code and let me know if this fulfills your requirements.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks! You should probably add, though, that this goes into the `functions.php` file of your theme.